# Windows CA Certificate Template Supersedence

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, certificate-authority

I have an internal Microsoft Windows CA (Windows Server 2012R2). I have a CodeSigning Template issued to a small number of users, valid for 6 years. Now i wanted to supersede the 6-year template with another one with a shorter validity.

I duplicated the template, changed the value of "Validity period" from 6 to 3 years, and added the 6-year template unter "Superseded Templates". Then i disabled the 6-year template and enabled the 3-year template.

When i now go to a client and try "Renew the certificate with the same key", this does not work since the 6-year template is missing.

So my questsions:

- Is it at all possible to renew a certificate with the same key when the template used for this certificate is superseded?
- Do i need to keep the superseded template enabled?

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certificate Template supersedance is used by certificate autoenrollment component only. No other (I'm aware of) tools takes this setting into consideration.

When you do manual enrollment and/or existing certificate renewal, supersedence is not considered and requires exact template to request/renew.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need to supersedence here you can use Reenroll all Certificate Holders option in the Certificate Templates MMC
go to template , change what you need , then right click on template and Reenroll all Certificate Holders then this change will be affected on clients during 8 hours or you can use certuitl command to push changes using certutil -pulse