# ldaps certificate for connections using domain.local instead of fqdn

Tags: windows, ldap, domain, certificate, ad-certificate-services

We have multiple Windows Server 2016 AD Domain Controllers and we need to replace all LDAP connections with LDAPS connections. For High Availability we would like to  connect all LDAPS sessions to "domain.local". The problem is that all Domain Controllers have self-signed certificates registered to their FQDN. When a LDAPS session connects to "domain.local", one of the Domain Controllers answers with its own certificate and they do not match.

I could replace those self-signed certificates with new certificates containing the "domain.local" as a Subject Alternate Name. But I'm not sure that is the right way to go. I think it also breaks the auto-renewal process for these certificates, as it is not possible to supply a "domain.local" SAN to a certificate template.

There must be many more installations like ours, and I hate to re-invent the wheel, so there must be someone out there who has an answer for this?

TIA,
Wouter

Comment: `There must be many more installations like ours`. No, there are not.

Comment: Idk, how you deploy existing certificates, but all you need is to use `Kerberos Authentication` template and autoenrollment policy.

Comment: @GregAskew: OK, then please advise us the preferred way to setup a high available LDAPS connection?

Comment: @GregAskew the newer Kerberos Authentication certificate templates shipped by Microsoft does add *domain.local* to the SAN by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a Microsoft "Enterprise CA", the correct method would be to issue certificates to the DCs using the `"Kerberos Authentication"` template (as @Crypt32 has indicated). The `"Kerberos Authentication"` template will include not just the DC FQDN but also the FQDN of the domain in the SAN allowing connections directly as the domain name.

It's worth noting that the `"Domain Controller"` (Server 2000) and `"Domain Controller Authentication"` (Server 2003) templates are older versions than the `"Kerberos Authentication"` (Server 2008) template. I would recommend disabling those templates on your CA to prevent confusion.

Comment: The current certificate on the DC is of the type "Domain Controller Authentication". I edited the "Kerberos Authentication" template and added the "Domain Controller Authentication" template as superceded and then disabled the latter. Next I tried to renew the current certificate, hoping to get a new "Kerberos Authentication" certificate. But on requesting a renewal, I get an error that the "Domain Controller Authentication" certificate (which I disabled) is unavailable.

Comment: I think I found the answer to my own question here <https://serverfault.com/questions/892639/windows-ca-certificate-template-supersedence>

Comment: Yeah, I would recommend making a new enrollment with the KA template rather than trying to auto-renew an older template cert to a newer template. Don't forget to remove the older certs as well.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little old, but this MSFT guide for creating a new ["Domain Controller Authentication (Kerberos)" certificate template](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-hybrid-cert-whfb-settings-pki#domain-controller-certificate-template) (to support Windows Hello) steps you nicely through creating a new template and superseding the previous DC certificate templates. (Skip the rest of the document when it starts discussing Enrollment Certificates.)

The new template is based on the Kerberos Authentication template (since you need the "KDC Authentication" OID), but it updates the encryption algorithm to RSA with a keylength of 2048. RSA is more performant than the legacy algorithm in the built-in Kerberos template.

I do this on all my DCs now, even in environments without Windows Hello.